# How to show embeded osm map in one language(german)?

Tags: javascript, html, openstreetmap

I'm new to OSM and got a world map enabled in a web page. I saw a possibility to switch languages for the map on a osm page. But can't find a tutorial how to set the wished langugage in a embeded map? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the domain name accordingly. For example, `openstreetmap.org` displays English, while `openstreetmap.de` displays German. Make use of this possibility.

Comment: I changed the tiles provider to https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png and it worked, thanks!